# Reidrect to local site

Tags: forms, email, redirect

I have this form where i need it to send an e-mail and everything is working perfectly, but when it redirects to a site i can only get it to redirect to an online site, but i need it to redirect back to the local index file.

I am creating an app, in phonegap, so i need it to go back, and not online.

My form code look like this:

```
    form action="http://scripts.dandomain.dk/formMail.asp" method="post">
```

## Indsend svar

```
     Fornavn:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Fornavn" size="25" placeholder="Fornavn" required>
    <br>
    Efternavn: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Efternavn" size="25" placeholder="Efternavn" required>
    <br>
    Tlf. nr.: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Tlf. nr." size="25" placeholder="Tlf. nr." required>
    <br>
    By: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Post nr." size="25" placeholder="By" required>
    <br>
    E-mail:<br>
    <input type="email" name="E-mail" size="25" placeholder="E-mail" required>
    <br>
    accepter konkurrence betingelser:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" required name="betinglser" value="acceptere betingelser">
    <br><br>

            <input type="hidden" name="IP" value="%%IP_ADR%%">
            <input type="hidden" name="Dato" value="%%NICE_DATE%%">

    <input type="hidden" name="DSuccess_URL" value="http://www.kavwer.dk/tak.html">

     <input type="hidden" name="totalSum" id="totalSum" value="" readonly>

      <button id="myBtn" alt="submit">Indsend</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form action="localPage.php" method="post">
```

"action" attribute is use to specify where the form data will be submitted to, put the value of action equal to your local site, it will redirect there to process the form.

Comment: sorry to be a bit newbie, but where do i put it in, cause there is already a form action which make the form sent a mail?